# Como fazer o evento 'focusout' de um input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Quero fazer um input aparecer quando eu clicar no *label*, quando eu clicar fora do input, ou seja, tirar o foco de tal, gostaria que ele desaparecesse.

HTML:

```
<form action="/" class="search">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="pesquisar">
            <span>Buscar</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="pesquisar">
        <button type="submit" class="send-search"></button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var label = $('.search label'),
        input = $('.search label + input');

    label.on('click', function() {
        if (input.is(':focus')) {
            input.css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            input.css({
                'display': 'block'
            }).focus();
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olá,

HTML:

```
<form action="/" class="search">
<fieldset>
    <label for="pesquisar" id="meuLabel">
        <span>Buscar</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="meuInput">
    <button type="submit" class="send-search">OK</button>
</fieldset>
```

Javascritpt:

```
$(function(){

var label = $('#meuLabel'),
    input = $('#meuInput');

input.hide();

label.on('click', function(){
    input.show();
});

input.on('focusout', function(){
    $(this).hide();
})
```

});

Veja o Fiddle

[Veja o Fiddle com a resposta](https://jsfiddle.net/0r47bd3r/4/)

Mas você poderia considerar utilizar AngularJS ficaria muito mais fácil pra você:

[Google AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Fiz apenas alguns ajustes mas funcionou perfeitamente :D

Answer (score 1):

Para que quando você clique no label, vá para o input, precisa nomear o id, como o mesmo do for, exemplo:

```
<label for="pesquisar">
        Buscar
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="pesquisar">
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/tzavbfco/

Em questão do desaparecer, você quer que desapareça o input quanto o usuário clique fora do input?

**EDIT**

Para atender o que você gostaria, você poderia fazer assim:

```
$("#pesquisar").focusout(function(){
if($(this).val() == ""){
$(this).hide("slow", function(){
    $("label[for='pesquisar']").click(function(){
    $("#pesquisar").show("slow");
  })
});
}
})
```

Veja aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/tzavbfco/2/

Comment: Eu fiz isso mas continua a não funcionar :/

Comment: Dê uma olhada no JsFiddle

Comment: Exatamente! Quando o usuário clicar fora do input, o mesmo desaparece :D

Comment: O **buscar** é uma espécie de placeholder customizado, entende?

Comment: Entendi, então você quer que alterne quando clicar no "Buscar" apareça e quando clicar fora desapareça?

Comment: Isso! Veja os comentários da outra resposta, para que se possível tivesse uma verificação para ele desaparecer apenas quando estiver vazio.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo veja se era isto que gostaria...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer dessa forma...

```
<label for="pesquisar">Buscar</label>
<input type="text" id="pesquisar">
```

e o javascript assim...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('label').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      if (!$('#pesquisar').is(':visible')) {
        $('#pesquisar').fadeIn('fast');
      } 
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      if ($('#pesquisar').is(':visible')) {
        $('#pesquisar').fadeOut('fast');
      } 
    });
    $('#pesquisar').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Podes ver o exemplo aqui...
https://jsfiddle.net/h2svjn5u/

Answer (score 0):

Tipo assim?

```js
var pesquisar = $("#pesquisar");
pesquisar.hide();
$("label[for='pesquisar']").click(function() {
  if (pesquisar.val().length <= 0) {
    pesquisar.toggle();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="pesquisar">Buscar</label>
<input type="text" id="pesquisar">
```

Acredito que realizar um toggle para mostrar e esconder o input ao clicar em buscar seria mais viavel,  por que se voce colocar o evento para esconder o input ao clicar em qualquer lugar da pagina ele irá desparar muitas vezes desnecessariamente.

Comment: Isso! Porém quando o usuário clicar fora do input, o mesmo desaparece. Se possível fazer uma verificação, para ele desaparecer só quando estiver vazio, tipo `if (!$('#pesquisar').val().length)`, entende?